# Fix a page loader which is not running when clicking item from other pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-table

I have a page loader that runs whenever i click the items(hyperlinked) from a bootstrap-table and it runs perfectly fine.But when i paginates the table and then click any item from the from  the table then no loader appears.
**I am doing this project on django and using bootstrap-table (extension of bootstrap)**

Here is the code that is used for page loader

HTML:

```
<div id="pageloader">
<p class="display-4"><strong>This may take some time so sit back and relax.</strong></P>
<img src="{%static 'appname\img\preloader.gif'%}">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#pageloader
{
  background: rgb( 245, 245, 220);
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}


#pageloader img
{
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -32px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
}
#pageloader p {
    margin-top: 18%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JS:

```
<script>

$(function(){
  $('a.explorelink').click(function(){
    $("#pageloader").fadeIn();
  });
});

</script>
```

How make the page loader works even when i click any item from another page ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding a click to `'a.explorelink'` only. You could try removing the class selector and attach click to every `<a>` :

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $("#pageloader").fadeIn();
  });
```

Although it seems you want to bind click to some table element. It depends what your table element is like. If you have the table in html you can just add the onClick there.

```
<table onClick={()=> querySelector(#pageloader).fadein()}/>
```

Comment: i already tried without class selector but it didn't work